# Serilog Date not being appended to log filename

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I have Serilog setup and logging in my application, however the date is not being appended to filename. The log file gets created as `Log-.log` instead of `Log-20220302.log`. Relevant code is shown below. The nuget package `Serilog.Sinks.File` has been installed. Any ideas why?

```
public override void Bind(ref IContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(
            () => new LoggerFactory(
                new ILoggerProvider[]
                {
                    new SerilogLoggerProvider(
                        new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .CreateLogger()),
                    new DebugLoggerProvider(),
                }).AddSerilog(),
            DependencyScope.Singleton);

        container.Register(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>), DependencyScope.Singleton);
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="C:\logs\Log-.log" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Day" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the double period in the file name. Example output apilog.20220114.log

```
// API appsettings.json
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "System": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "Enrich": [
            "FromLogContext",
            "WithMachineName",
            "WithProcessId",
            "WithThreadId"
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
            { "Name": "Console" },
            {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                    "path": "%PROGRAMDATA%\\MyLogs\\apilog..log",
                    "rollingInterval": "Day",
                    "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                    "fileSizeLimitBytes": 4194304,
                    "retainedFileCountLimit": 6,
                    "shared": true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: It is unclear what the change from "-" to "." has to do with this question. Can you add some info why this is needed to get this working?